# mipsel-gdb breakpoint from source code

Tags: gdb, breakpoints, mips

It seems that gdb is failing to find breakpoints if a class is implemented in the header file. Therefore I am trying to force a breakpoint from the source. I guess I need the mips equivalent of asm("int3"). Any ideas?

PS: asm("break 3") does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `__volatile__ __asm__("break");`